# HP Workstation z640 SSD not detected

Tags: ssd, workstation

I have a z640 workstation, I ran out of space in the source SSD, for this reason I resorted to changing the original SSD for one that had 1Tb. When installing Windows 10 from USB everything works correctly until the point arrives at which the wizard should detect the SSD where to install the OS but it is not detected.

I wonder if I need any specific driver that I would have to load at this point.

Make a clone of the original SSD and this if it works and is detected with the new SSD, so I deduce (I don't know if wrongly) that it is a matter of configuration or drivers. Now what I need is to be able to install from scratch to have a clean installation.

Does anyone have any idea what I can do?

Comment: does your BIOS see the new SSD?

Comment: Yes, BIOS see SSD.

Answer (score 0):

When you boot, you'll need to enter the BIOS and check that the SSD is visible to the BIOS.

If the drive *is* visible in the BIOS, then you should be able to proceed with setting it up as a boot drive. using the built in wizard on the BIOS.

If not, then it may be worth trying the following:

- Check the SATA cable is properly connected to both the motherboard and the SSD (if you have a new SATA cable at your disposal, then it is worth trying it out to determine if that's the problem).
- Check the power cable to the SSD and do the same as I mentioned above, check the cable and try a different power cable from your power supply if there is one available in your unit (there most definitely will be).
- You've got bad luck and the SSD is just a bad SSD. If you have another machine to hand, try the SSD in that and see if it's visible in the BIOS. If it is, then it's likely an issue with the motherboard of the PC you're trying to install the SSD into.

Source: I build computers as a hobby for myself and friends and work in infrastructure, I've done the above procedure plenty of times

Comment: As per op comment the BIOS already sees the system. Its not a cabling fault.

Comment: At time of posting, OP hadn't clarified that in a comment (or I just failed to notice it). Their post was also unclear due to a few grammar mistakes. I'm not a grammar Nazi and thought it be better to clarify instead of knock OP's grammar.

In addition, I still provided an answer that fits OP's question at the very start of my answer, I just simply added to my answer given multiple users had asked for clarification of the BIOS, and so thought to wrap it into one answer. Apologies if providing an answer that covers different scenarios isn't acceptable... I guess?

Answer (score 0):

In the Pre-OS environment, HP Workstations can use either Option ROM (OROM) or a Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI) driver for configuration and management of the RAID controllers. z640 usually includes a 2 port 6g Intel SATA RAID controller (SATA) and a secondary 4 port 6g SATA RAID controller (sSATA).

The default shipping configuration is (again, usually) set to All Legacy OROM. This can be changed in BIOS Setup under Advanced > Option ROM Launch Policy.

**The OROM or UEFI driver is not available when the SATA or sSATA controllers are set to AHCI.**

When the Option ROM Launch Policy is set to All Legacy, the SATA and sSATA OROM will only display at power on if there are two or more RAID capable devices attached to the controller, or a single device is attached that contains RAID metadata.

When the Option ROM Launch Policy is set to UEFI, the legacy OROM will not display and management of RAID can be performed in 3rd Party Option ROM Management from the BIOS Startup Menu. I think this is what you need - Windows 10 should then be able to detect the SSD (in legacy mode).

Answer (score 0):

For your SSD to be detected on HP Workstation z640 perform the following tasks

1. Download the official hp driver from https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp96001-96500/sp96420.exe
2. Extract files from sp96420.exe using 7-zip
3. From the extracted files open folder named "Drivers"
4. Locate file iaStorA.inf
5. Copy iaStorA.inf to the usb drive that you have Windows 10 installation media on
6. Begin installing Windows 10 on your HP Workstation z640
7. Once prompted, to select a drive to install Windows 10 click the link "Load driver"
8. In the "Load driver" prompt click "Browse"
9. navigate to the driver iaStorA.inf
10. select the driver iaStorA.inf
11. Click "Next"
12. Your SSD should be visible now.

note: if you do not see the SSD drive, then format the drive on another machine as a GPT and try the above steps again

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete; do not append to it with comments; .